# Using If then logic in R to create a new variable

Tags: r

I am working with a dataset in R and have some missing values. I am trying to figure out how to create a new variable (z) that follows the following logic "if Y has a missing value then Z's output is 0, if Y does not have a missing value then the output is one. Note, please see example below.

(Original Output

```
    x----y
    1    abc
    2    svc
    3    (blank)
    4    ads 
    5    (blank)
    6     adf
```

(Desired Output)

```
x----y---------z
1    abc       1
2    svc       1
3    (blank)   0
4    ads       1
5    (blank)   0
6     adf      1
```

Comment: I think you want `Z <- as.numeric(!is.na(Y))` if your "blanks" are actually `NA`. If they are literally empty character strings, then `Z <- as.numeric(nzchar(Y))`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your missing values in `y` are coded as `NA` in your data frame and then you can assign a new column `z` to your data frame `df` using the `ifelse` function.

```
df$z <- ifelse(is.na(df$y), 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether the blank values are `NA` or string , you need to use

```
df$z <- ifelse(is.na(df$y), 0, 1)
```

Say if string contains the word 'blank'

```
df$z <- ifelse(df$y=='blank', 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
df$z <- +nzchar(df$y)
```